# Laravel & Buefy - Get the old selected value

Tags: laravel, buefy, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and Buefy... I'm trying to keep the old value for the `<b-select>,` but my code didn't work.

```php
<b-field>
    <b-select name="nationality_id"
              placeholder="{{__('site.nationality')}}"
              icon="flag"
              icon-pack="fas"
              expanded>

        @foreach ($nationalities as $nationality)
            <option value="{{ $nationality->id }}" {{(old('nationality_id')==$nationality->id)? 'selected':''}}>
                {{ $nationality->name}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </b-select>
</b-field>
```

I know that I need `v-model` but I need help with using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` prop, for example `value="{{old('nationality_id')}}"`